# Nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'long com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.exhaust(java.io.InputStream)']

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, google-directory-api

Can anyone please help me to resolve below issue. Just yesterday, It was working fine and suddenly I got below error. I tried to remove StoredCredential file and generate new one but same error. I tried to add latest guava dependency in pom.xml but no luck. I don't know what changed suddenly. Thank you for looking into this. Below is stack trace.

```
2021-01-20 12:58:25.101 ERROR 11620 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/user-details] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'long com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.exhaust(java.io.InputStream)'] with root cause

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'long com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.exhaust(java.io.InputStream)'
    at com.google.api.client.http.ConsumingInputStream.close(ConsumingInputStream.java:40) ~[google-http-client-1.35.0.jar:1.35.0]
    at java.base/java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.close(InflaterInputStream.java:232) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.close(GZIPInputStream.java:137) ~[na:na]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._closeInput(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:254) ~[jackson-core-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserBase.close(ParserBase.java:369) ~[jackson-core-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonParser.close(JacksonParser.java:47) ~[google-http-client-jackson2-1.35.0.jar:na]
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:363) ~[google-http-client-1.35.0.jar:1.35.0]
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:335) ~[google-http-client-1.35.0.jar:1.35.0]
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:79) ~[google-http-client-1.35.0.jar:1.35.0]
    at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:73) ~[google-http-client-1.35.0.jar:1.35.0]
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse.parseAs(HttpResponse.java:449) ~[google-http-client-1.35.0.jar:1.35.0]
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307) ~[google-oauth-client-1.20.0.jar:1.20.0]
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.executeRefreshToken(Credential.java:570) ~[google-oauth-client-1.20.0.jar:1.20.0]
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489) ~[google-oauth-client-1.20.0.jar:1.20.0]
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:217) ~[google-oauth-client-1.20.0.jar:1.20.0]
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:880) ~[google-http-client-1.35.0.jar:1.35.0]
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419) ~[google-api-client-1.20.0.jar:1.20.0]
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352) ~[google-api-client-1.20.0.jar:1.20.0]
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469) ~[google-api-client-1.20.0.jar:1.20.0]
    at com.schools.nyc.userdetails.service.UserDetailService.createGsuiteAccount(UserDetailService.java:429) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.schools.nyc.userdetails.controller.UserDetailController.createUser(UserDetailController.java:208) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) ~[servlet-api.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[servlet-api.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-websocket.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.39]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-util.jar:9.0.39]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) ~[na:na]
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you deploy to a different server?  Does the server have the same library versions as your build environment?  This exception is almost always caused by a library version mismatch.

Comment: No. It's same server. I am working on localhost.

Comment: Did you update the Google libraries? Did you do a clean build? Did you change library versions?

Comment: No change in Libraries. I also tried to clean the build and try.

Comment: <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
    <!--   <version>1.20.0</version> -->
  </dependency>

Comment: I just comment the version and it started working. Funny thing is, it was there before and was working fine. Thank you for your time and help to look into this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
          <!--   <version>1.20.0</version> -->
</dependency>
```

From above dependency, I have comment out the version and it started working.